# NULL not allowed for column "ID" H2 Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am using Java EE with Wildfly 12. I have the following SQL table scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE AUTHOR ("ID" INTEGER primary key, "FIRSTNAME" VARCHAR(50) not null, "SECONDNAME" VARCHAR(50) not null);
CREATE TABLE BOOK ("ID" INTEGER primary key, "TITLE" VARCHAR(50) not null, "AUTHOR" INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY ("AUTHOR") REFERENCES AUTHOR("ID"));
```

I want to execute the following insert:

```
INSERT INTO AUTHOR("SECONDNAME","FIRSTNAME") values ('a', 'b');
INSERT INTO BOOK("TITLE","AUTHOR") values ('bookTitle', 1);
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="script"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="script"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="META-INF/create.sql"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source" value="META-INF/drop.sql"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/load.sql"/>
```

This works when I explicitly insert ID. However, the ID has to be auto-generated. My entity classes:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

// rest of fields, getters, and setters omitted

}

@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
// Again, rest of the fields, getters and setters omitted
}
```

I've tried all generation strategies (AUTO, IDENTITY, SEQUENCE). As I said, if I explicitly set IDs in my SQL, the SQL works, but I encounter the same problem when using entityManager.persist...

```
@POST
@Path("/create")
public void createAuthor(Author author) {
    entityManager.persist(author);
}
```

All of the above gives me:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement: ...
```

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have only stated that the column `ID` is `INTEGER` and `PRIMARY KEY`. You have never set that the column should be auto increment, so the error message is right.  Change your DDL to:

```
CREATE TABLE AUTHOR (
    "ID" INTEGER primary key auto_increment,
    "FIRSTNAME" VARCHAR(50) not null,
    "SECONDNAME" VARCHAR(50) not null
);

CREATE TABLE BOOK (
    "ID" INTEGER primary key auto_increment,
    "TITLE" VARCHAR(50) not null,
    "AUTHOR" INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY ("AUTHOR") REFERENCES AUTHOR("ID")
);
```